# How to instantiate GIcon

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I need to show an icon on `Gio.MenuItem` with `set_icon()` method. But `set_icon()` expects to receive a GIcon object.
How to create a GIcon object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gio.Icon` is just an interface. It is implemented by `Gio.ThemedIcon`, `Gio.FileIcon`, `Gio.BytesIcon`, etc. So you would would use those.

Comment: How to create a `Gio.FileIcon` with a object-oriented format?
I can instantiate like this:

`arquiv = Gio.File.new_for_path("home.png") ico = Gio.FileIcon.new(arquiv)`

But that seems to be far from object-oriented programming.

Comment: I expected a class and a constructor. Like this:

`arquiv = Gio.File('any_path/any_file.png')`
`ico = Gio.FileIcon(arquiv)`

Comment: Generally you want to use the .new() functions. That said most of the time you can use the constructor directly but it takes keywords for the GObject property names. As in `Gio.FileIcon(file=arquiv)`.

Comment: Where can I find this information of property names of these classes?

Comment: Apparently this is not possible with Gio.File. It seems that it does not implement a constructor. It seems that we can only to instantiate through a static methods.
`new_for_commandline_arg`, `Gio.File.new_for_path`, `Gio.File.new_for_uri`, `Gio.File.new_tmp`, `Gio.File.parse_name`